# How to redirect http to https on aws ec2 instance using classic load balancer through Java project?

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I did not generate key pair while creating EC2 instance,hence could not access my ec2 instance.I am able to access https://example.com .
Now I want my website to be redirected to https://example.com when someone hits http://example.com .I am using classic load balancer on aws.
How to achieve this though files in Java project only.

According to AWS docs link-https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect
I tried it,but this is not working.

I created file elasticbeanstalk.config inside **.ebextensionfolder** which is placed just under my Project folder-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}

  <Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost on

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

The site is not redirecting to https.Do I need to change anything in above file.Or the folder .ebextensionfolder  needed to be placed in some different path.Has anyone used the above approach and made it working?

Comment: Improve your question by correctly formatting. For the code sections, use the `{}` to properly format the text. Otherwise it is hard to see mistakes.

Comment: See this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Comment: @hephalump the whole problem is that I cant acces  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf as I could not connect to ec2 instance.

Comment: Are you using a AWS Elastic load balancer

Comment: Yes aws classic load balancer